# Any multi-currency accounting ledger that lets me use BTC?

Tags: taxes, accounting, merchants

Are there any online or open source (i.e., free, or at least cheap) accounting systems that do multi-currency so that I can record revenues and payments made using BTCs in the same system that I use for USDs?

If not, are there any suggestions for how best to do this?

Comment: GNUCash doesn't allow custom currencies but it does have many currencies, so can just choose one that you know you won't be using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found Kashoo.  Freemium, or $10/month.  Haven't used it yet though.

- http://www.kashoo.com

Also, what might work, Aqilla:

- http://www.aqilla.com/multi-currency-ledger

Infinity PFM (Personal Finance Manager) can read transactions from the Bitcoin.org client:
 - http://launchpad.net/infinitypfm

Ledger:

- http://www.ledger-cli.org  <-- Command line only, no GUI.
- http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/155gw5   <--- Writeup

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://my-btc.info, a free page to monitor the portfolio of digital currencies with profit / loss calculation including BTC and many, many other alt-coins.

Diskussions about the tool at the bitcointalk forum: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=220238.0

Also, I must say that Dario (the webmaster) is a great guy. Unbelievable what has been implemented in the last two months and he is always open to new suggestions.
Thanks and Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Xero accounting: http://www.xero.com/

It's free(gratis) with an extensive API so you could add BTC transactions if you're programmatically-inclined and supports multiple currencies.

EDIT: Maybe it's not so free

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out Bitcoin Transaction Coordinator for NetSuite.  http://www.btc4erp.com.  And there is a free offer to work with NetSuite if you are a startup.

It also has built in pricing for Bitcoin exchange rates and will seamless allow accepting Bitcoin and paying bills.  It appears to be the first fully integrated platform.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using https://www.blockonomics.co. It only supports BTC, they have plans to support more crypto later

You can track multiple BTC address, see history and export transactions for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

[CryptFolio](https://cryptfolio.com) supports multiple currencies and is [designed for handling cryptocurrency inventory](https://cryptfolio.com/tax). The [trial plan](https://cryptfolio.com/pricing) is free and the paid plans are, in my opinion, affordable.

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of CryptFolio.

Answer (score 0):

BitBook, open source: https://github.com/C-Otto/BitBook/

The purpose of BitBook is to track your own coins by organizing on-chain transactions and their corresponding addresses. If you are able to spend coins for an address, you can mark the address as owned. In all other cases you can mark addresses as foreign. BitBook helps you identify related addresses and transactions where the ownership status is still unknown, so that you can add the missing information and, over time, create a complete picture of your owned coins.

Beware: There is no export, yet.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.