# Is there an asset tracking software that supports Bitcoin? (Better than GnuCash)

Tags: accounting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any multi-currency accounting ledger that lets me use BTC?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/any-multi-currency-accounting-ledger-that-lets-me-use-btc)

I'm looking for a way to manage all of my assets. I have various assets in multiple currencies & investment instruments.

I think I would like to try using a software that works with [double-entry bookkeeping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system). I'm trying out GnuCash so far, and it seems to do a decent job:

1. It can easily track all Fiat currencies and has automatically updated prices.
2. [Can be made to work with Bitcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=29884.0) using the XXX custom currency code.
3. Is a tad complicated to begin with, but I think over time it's worth it.

Frankly, the one thing I'm missing is integration of an Mt. Gox price feed and the ugliness of writing XXX instead of BTC.

Comment: I think mainline GnuCash will never support bitcoin. They only support ISO4217 currencies, and ISO will never assign BTC to bitcoin. Partially because they want no part in it, and partially because the [BT? range of currency codes is already allocated to Bhutan.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhutanese_ngultrum) Perhaps a fork is in order?